# git push heroku master results in issues with authenticity and host key failing

Tags: heroku, ssh, rsa, push, fingerprint

I am doing my first push to Heroku and this is what I see

```
$ git push heroku master
The authenticity of host 'heroku.com (50.19.85.156)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is 8b:48:5e:67:0e:c9:16:47:32:f2:87:0c:1f:c8:60:ad.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? no
Host key verification failed.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I have looked at the Heroku doc page https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git-repository-ssh-fingerprints and it tells me

> Manually verifying
>
> The current Heroku SSH Git fingerprint is
>   8b:48:5e:67:0e:c9:16:47:32:f2:87:0c:1f:c8:60:ad.
>
> When you first git push heroku master, please manually match the
>   provided SSH key to this fingerprint.

Ok I know what the current SSH Git fingerprint is but I have no idea what the **provided SSH key** is. Also I have no idea how I would match the two.

Also I tried verifying with DNS. I followed the following in instructions

> Verifying with DNS
>
> You can make use of our SSHFP DNS records by adding the following
>   lines to your ~/.ssh/config

```
Host heroku.com  
  VerifyHostKeyDNS yes
```

So first I realized there was no `config` file in my `~/.ssh/` directory. So I made the `config` file and added the two lines. Then when I tried to push again this is what I saw

```
$ git push heroku master
Bad owner or permissions on /home/max/.ssh/config
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: I'm not sure this will fix your problem, but you need to select yes when it prompts you to continue connecting:  ``Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? no`` --> ``yes`` The "provided" SSH key is the one you see in your shell prompt (when it says the authenticity can't be established.) You'll see it matches the SSH Git fingerprint on the website

Comment: @Moritz I chose 'Yes' and it seemed to work. Thanks. The reason I did not choose 'Yes' is because I thought something bad would happen. When you see 'authenticity of host could not be established' and you are a beginner that just jumped into this, it is scary. Feel free to supply the answer and I will mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On your initial push to heroku, when you are prompted to continue connecting: `Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?` you need to select `yes`. The "provided" SSH key is the RSA fingerprint outputted in your shell prompt. Note that it matches the Heroku SSH Git fingerprint listed on the doc page.